Updated sys canceled
updates cancled
atach
I attempted a system update, but it failed midway with an error code (specific code not mentioned). Now, my system is stuck on startup or a rollback. What are the best steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue without losing data?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
